# error with XML parsing

Tags: java, xml, parsing

To parse an XML String I have googled and I have found [an example on how to do that](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0573.html), but it dosn't work for me!

When I declare NodeList the following error appeared: `required:groovy.util.NodeList, found org.w3c.dom.NodeList`

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      System.out.println("*********test2*********");
 InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(var2)); 
 Document parse = builder.parse(is);
 NodeList nodes = parse.getElementsByTagName("step");

 for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
{
   Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

       NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("step");
       Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
       System.out.println("Name: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                System.out.println("______test3_____");
 }
```

**Upadte:**
   I have changed the code  using this code but another error appear I think it related to the structure of my xml String:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
        .newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(var2));
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(is);

NodeList nl = document.getElementsByTagName("step");
Element el = (Element) nl.item(0);
Text elText = (Text) el.getChunks();
String theValue = elText.getNodeValue();
System.out.println("value"+theValue);
```

The error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.opensymphony.com
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1315)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1282)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:283)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1194)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1090)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1003)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at DAOKPI.Main.main(Main.java:99)
```

Answer (score 4):

You imported the wrong class: You seem to have imported `groovy.util.NodeList` but need `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` instead.

Replace `import groovy.util.NodeList;` at the top of your source file with  `import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;`.

Comment: have done that but the error :can not find symbol :methode getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)!

Comment: I have updated my post with another code but always their are errors :(

Comment: @rym: your XML parser is trying to load the DTD to resolve an entity and fails to resolve the host mentioned. Either make sure that that host is resolvable (i.e. is reachable) *or* provide your own `EntityResolver` that resolves the entity in question.

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer ,hello what is EntityResolver I don't know it! In fact I don't know why this node  <!DOCTYPE workflow PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//DTD OSWorkflow 2.8//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/workflow_2_8.dtd"> makes trouble!!

Comment: @rym: hint: use your favorite search engine with the term "EntityResolver" and thou shalst be enlightened!